# Pandas groupby mean absolute deviation

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Product Group    Product ID    Units Sold    Revenue    Rev/Unit
A                451           8             $16        $2
A                987           15            $40        $2.67
A                311           2             $5         $2.50
B                642           6             $18        $3.00
B                251           4             $28        $7.00
```

I want to transform it to look like this:

```
Product Group    Units Sold    Revenue    Rev/Unit   Mean Abs Deviation
A                25            $61        $2.44      $0.24
B                10            $46        $4.60      $2.00
```

The Mean Abs Deviation column is to be performed on the Rev/Unit column in the first table. The tricky thing is taking into account the respective weights behind the Rev/Unit calculation.

For example taking a straight MAD of Product Group A's Rev/Unit would yield $0.26. However after taking weight into consideration, the MAD would be $0.24.

I know to use groupby to get the simple summation for units sold and revenue, but I'm a bit lost on how to do the more complicated calculations of the next 2 columns.

Also while we're giving advice/help---is there any easier way to create/paste tables into SO posts??

UPDATE:

Would a solution like this work? I know it will for the summation fields, but not sure how to implement for the latter 2 fields.

```
 grouped_df=df.groupby("Product Group")
 grouped_df.agg({
   'Units Sold':'sum',
   'Revenue':'sum',
   'Rev/Unit':'Revenue'/'Units Sold',
   'MAD':some_function})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to clarify what the "weights" are, I assumed the weights are the number of units sold, but that gives a different results from yours:

```
pv = df.pivot_table( rows='Product Group',
                     values=[ 'Units Sold', 'Revenue' ],
                     aggfunc=sum )
pv[ 'Rev/Unit' ] = pv.Revenue / pv[ 'Units Sold' ]
```

this gives:

```
               Revenue  Units Sold  Rev/Unit
Product Group                               
A                   61          25      2.44
B                   46          10      4.60
```

As for WMAD:

```
def wmad( prod ):
    idx = df[ 'Product Group' ] == prod
    w = df[ 'Units Sold' ][ idx ]
    abs_dev = np.abs ( df[ 'Rev/Unit' ][ idx ] - pv[ 'Rev/Unit' ][ prod ] )
    return sum( abs_dev * w ) / sum( w )

pv[ 'Mean Abs Deviation' ] = [ wmad( idx ) for idx in pv.index ]
```

which as I mentioned gives different result

```
               Revenue  Units Sold  Rev/Unit  Mean Abs Deviation
Product Group                                                   
A                   61          25      2.44              0.2836
B                   46          10      4.60              1.9200
```

Comment: Is there any way to insert a function into the agg method? See edited OP for more details

Comment: You can use a lambda function, invoking a full function from that if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From your suggested solution, you can use a lambda function to operate on each row e.g:

```
'Rev/Unit': lambda x: calculate_revenue_per_unit(x)
```

Bear in mind that x is a tuple for each row, so you'll need to unpack that within your `calculate_revenue_per_unit` function.